# Using a generic base class as a parameter of a method

Tags: c#, .net, mono, derived-class, generic-type-argument

I have the following classes

```
public class A<T>
{
}
public class B<T> : A<T>
{
}
public class C1 : B<string>
{
}
public class C2 : B<int>
{
}
```

What I would like to do, is have a method which can take any class derived from `B<T>`, like `C1` or `C2` as a parameter. But declaring a method as

```
public void MyMethod(B<T> x)
```

does not work, it yields the compiler error

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246)

I am quite stuck here. Creating a non-generic baseclass for `B<T>` won't work, since I wouldn't be able to derive from `A<T>` that way. The only (ugly) solution I could think of is to define an empty dummy-interface which is "implemented" by `B<T>`. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a generic method:

```
public void MyMethod<T> (B<T> x)
```

And you can call it like so:

```
MyMethod(new B<string>());
MyMethod(new C1());
MyMethod(new C2());
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew that it would work, if I make the method generic, but I thought that I had to specify the type upon calling explicitely.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Specify `T` on the method:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(B<T> x)
```

or perhaps on the class containing the method:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public void MyMethod(B<T> x){}
}
```

In both cases you'll need the same type constraints (if any) specified on the original class(es)

Answer (score 3):

Change the signature of your method like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(B<T> x)
```